# "Access Denied" when trying to access AWS Lightsail database

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, database-administration, amazon-lightsail, navicat

I'm trying to connect to my AWS Lightsail database instance with Navicat Premium 15.0.21 (newest available version at the time of posting).

My database is in public mode. I copied and pasted the endpoint, username, and password straight into Navicat; Port 3306. Lightsail reports the database as "Available."

These settings have not changed for over 24 hours and I have rebooted the instance multiple times but Navicat keeps telling me "Access Denied"

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpSdg.png)

I have also tried connecting with a VPN via multiple countries. And I have tried to connect with DBeaver; same issue (Access Denied). I'm running Navicat on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like you can connect fine, and that the problem is user / password.

Comment: @Tim Interesting. Unfortunately I have also tried changing the password, still no login luck. And dbmasteruser is just the default username it gives you when you create the instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when setting up the connection in MySQL Workbench.

The cause was the following:
When you double click to copy the password from the AWS page, it appends an enter at the end. This is copied into the password field as well. So the password is not correct.

Copy the password by selecting it character by character. Then there will be no enter at the end and the connection will be correct.

Comment: Truly ridiculous! I can't believe this was the issue. Thank you! Working fine now